# mysql st procedure if elseif error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have table `users` with columns `name varchar(25)` and `pass varchar(50)`.
I need to create stored procedure that removes column for right user with correct pass if it exists.
If I code something like this it throws me error 1064 (syntax error):

```
delimiter //
create procedure delete_user(newname varchar(25), newpass(50))
begin
    declare usersCount int;
    select count(name,pass) from users into usersCount where name=newname && pass=newpass;
    if usersCount !=0 then
        alter table users drop column where name=newname && pass=newpass;
    else if
        select there is no souch user\!;
    end if;
end//
delimiter;
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact error. But I suspect it's because you need to single-quote the string literal `SELECT 'there is no such user!'` and `COUNT()` only accepts one argument but you have `count(name,pass)`.  It would help if you edit above to show an example of the rows in the `users` table, together with the output you are trying to produce. You would not want to drop columns from the table with an `ALTER` but rather `DELETE FROM users WHERE name = newname AND pass= newpass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have succed,I'w used `DML` instead `DDL` syntax...

`...
delete from users where name=newname && pass=newpass;
...`

The answer was infront of my nose...